# Can't seem to select an element by ID when there's a colon and underscore in it

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to automate some of our data input and can't seem to find the selector for a specific input element.

This is the element I'm trying to get to with my code:

```
<input role="combobox" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="No Selection" title="" 
aria-owns="154:_listSelect" class="rcmpaginatedselectinput rcmpaginatedselectitem rcmpaginatedselect_accessible" 
"="" onclick="juic.fire(&quot;153:&quot;,&quot;_click&quot;,event);" 
id="153:_input" onblur="juic.fire(&quot;153:&quot;,&quot;_onBlur&quot;,event);" 
onkeyup="juic.fire(&quot;153:&quot;,&quot;_click&quot;,event);" 
onkeydown="juic.fire(&quot;153:&quot;,&quot;_click&quot;,event);">
```

However, when I try to select the `#153:_input` id, node throws the following error:

`(node:5880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#153:_input' is not a valid selector.`

How can I select this element?

Here's my code:

```
(async() => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [
            '--start-maximized'],
        headless: false
    })

    //launch page
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 800})

    await page.goto("I'm not allowed to display the URL")
    
    await page.waitForSelector('#153:_input')
    await page.type('#153:_input', 'type instead of selecting')



})()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `#153:_input` is not even a valid CSS selector. But, you could try treating the ID as an attribute and use the attribute selector.

```js
await page.waitForSelector('[id="153:_input"]');
await page.type('[id="153:_input"]', 'type instead of selecting');
```

Comment: So I just tried that and now it gives me this: `(node:22154) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: [id="153:_input"]`

Comment: I tried this code generating the html you shared (`await page.setContent('<input role="combobox" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="No Selection" title=""aria-owns="154:_listSelect" class="rcmpaginatedselectinput rcmpaginatedselectitem rcmpaginatedselect_accessible""="" onclick="juic.fire(&quot;153:&quot;,&quot;_click&quot;,event);"id="153:_input" onblur="juic.fire(&quot;153:&quot;,&quot;_onBlur&quot;,event);"onkeyup="juic.fire(&quot;153:&quot;,&quot;_click&quot;,event);"onkeydown="juic.fire(&quot;153:&quot;,&quot;_click&quot;,event);">');`)  and it worked :/

Comment: So the weird thing is when I go into the console and do `document.querySelector('[id="153:_input"]')` it finds it... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind it works! I forgot to add the waitForSelector :) Thanks @hardkoded!